# calling C# from c++ com add-in

Tags: c#, c++, com, add-in, ccw

I have a COM add-in written in C++ (not C++ / CLI). I want to call a C# library objects/methods from this C++ com library.

I guess the CCW comes into picture here, which i am currently reading about.

Are there any quick pointers to this stuff from your experience?

Also, i have a method in my Com add-in that i would like my C# library code to call - i.e. a method pointer invocation.

Can you help telling me how i can do this please - i.e. how do i go about passing the method pointer to the C# code so it can call on it later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this links for you:
[COM Interop Part 1 Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekdxstex(VS.80).aspx)
[Create DCOM application from within .Net environment: Part V](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/710262008063529am/7.aspx)
[C++ to C# call](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/bridge.aspx)